# Kafka Client get retention.bytes programmatically

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Using Kafka Admin from Java I'm trying to find how can I get the `retention.bytes` and `retention.ms` from a `topic`

The only thing I found in the API is this

```
    adminClient.describeConfigs(Collection<ConfigRsources>???).values().get(ConfigResource???).get().get(String).
```

In case this is the way, not sure where I can get where it supposed to be passed.

The last string I guess it would be the config name `retention.byte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where I can get

Read through the [Javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#describeConfigs-java.util.Collection-). ConfigResource has a Type enum.

Then describing accepts a collection and returns a map via values, keyed by items in that collection. Therefore, pull out the reference to its own variable for reuse.

Then I suggest using constants
rather than strings.

```
Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();                
config.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(config);
                         
ConfigResource resource = new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.TOPIC, "example");

Config topicConfig = client.describeConfigs(Collections.singletonList(resource)).values().get(resource);

topicConfig.get(TopicConfig.RETENTION_BYTES_CONFIG);
topicConfig.get(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG);
```